# I tried to run function push and pop but it gets reverted. I don't no what to do?

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.9;

contract Stack{

    uint public Count;
    uint[] public Storage;
    constructor(){
        Count = 0;
    }
    function Push(uint _value) public{
        Storage[Count] = _value;
        Count++;
    }
    function Pop() public{
        if(Count > 0){
            delete Storage[Count];
            Count--;
        }
    }
}
```

the transaction gets reverted. I don't no why
the error is in this line // Storage[Count] = _value;
and // delete Storage[Count];

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are two issues to address here:

1. The following line in `Push(uint _value)`:

```
Storage[Count] = _value;
```

This doesn't work, because you're not allowed to access an array element at a position that doesn't exist. Instead, you should do the following:

```
Storage.push(_value);
```

2. The following line in `Pop()`:

```
delete Storage[Count];
```

This is plain wrong, since the last element of the array would actually have an index of `Count - 1`. So you should instead do:

```
delete Storage[Count - 1];
```

**Side Note**: I would advise to use a mapping instead of an array, as it should be cheaper to use gas-wise. Especially since you're defining an external `Count` variable to keep track of the array limit.

Comment: without using built-in functions like push(); is there any way ?

Comment: @Naren I think you would need to used inline-assembly, but that would simply be duplicating what the `push()` method already does.

Comment: @Naren Also, I forgot to mention that you already have a `pop()` method that you could use. Would you like to have the internal implementation of both `push()` and `pop()`?

Comment: @Naren has this been resolved now?